# How to get multidimensional associative array to sub multidimensional associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative

I have a multidimensional PHP array, how can I get a multidimensional associative array where the key will be the value of `meetingId['0']` and value will be the value of `playback['0']`?

```
Array(
    [returncode] => Array([0] => SUCCESS)
    [message] => Array()
    [0] => Array(
        [meetingId] => Array([0] =>3049)
        [name] => Array([0] => Measurement)
        [playback] => Array([0] => mid2020)
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [meetingId] => Array([0] => 3048)
        [name] => Array([0] => Measurement)
        [playback] => Array([0] => mid2019)
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [meetingId] => Array([0] => 3047)
        [name] => Array([0] => Measurement)
        [playback] => Array([0] => mid2018)
    )
)
```

Result will be:

```
array('3049'=>'mid2020','3048'=>'mid2019','3047'=>'mid2018')
```

Comment: array_combine(array_column(array_column($room_recordings,"meetingId"),0),array_column(array_column($room_recordings,"playbackFormatUrl"),0))

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem,

```
$result = array_combine(array_column(array_column($room_recordings,"meetingId"),0), array_column(array_column($room_recordings,"playback"),0));
```